# Java: How check if two arrays are in same order?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I have two arrays:

```
String [] arr1 ={"You", "book"};
String [] arr2 ={"Do", "You", "like","book" };
```

I want to check if `arr1` match the `arr2` in terms of the same order. If `arr1` is `{"book", "You"}`, then `arr1` does not match `arr2`.

Alright, I think that my code is wrong, but anyway:

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[j]){
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run it, it always return `null` even my `arr1` does match `arr2`.

Comment: What do you want for `String[] arr1={"a", "b"}, arr2 = {"b", "c"};`?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Since no effort is posted, here's a hint: you can use the arrays' indexes to compare whether the word appears in order.

Comment: Take out the indexes of common words , if you just want for common words. And if you want all the elements of array1 should present in 2 ,then  iterate on second and till  you find first element of array1 and  then again iterate till you find next.

Comment: I pinpointed your problem, it's your nested loop. Only use one loop to compare. If the arrays are different sizes, well then you definitely know they're not the same. I was going to post as answer, but this just got closed :/.

Comment: public boolean isOrderedMatch(String[] arr1, String[] arr2){
  for (int i=0, j=0; i<arr1.length; i++,j++){
   System.out.println("i:" + i + ":" + arr1[i]);
   boolean matched = false;

     for (; j< arr2.length; j++){
      System.out.println("j:" + j + ":" + arr2[j]);
       
       if (arr1[i].equals(arr2[j])){
         System.out.println("Matched on elem: " + j);
          matched = true;
          break;
        }
      } 

      if(!matched){
       return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the elements in array 1 that aren't in array 2. This result should match array 1.

```
public static boolean withinAndInOrder(String[] a, String[] b) {
    return Arrays.equals(a, Arrays.stream(b)
                            .parallel()
                            .filter(element -> Arrays.binarySearch(a, element) >= 0)
                            .toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as I have a feeling this is some kind of assignment, I'm only going to drop a couple of hints.

You're currently iterating both Arrays. This means that you compare every item to every item in the other list. For example:

```
String[] arr1 = { "a", "b" }
String[] arr2 = { "a", "b" }
```

Due to your two loops, you're comparing "a" (`arr1[0]`) with "a" and "b" (`arr2[0]` and `arr2[1]`). What you really want is a single loop, and you compare the same index in both Arrays against each other.

As an extra tip; you might finish your loop but not have looked at every element in both arrays.

Also, side note; using `!=` for Strings isn't the best idea (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)).

Answer (score -1):

```
var i=0;
while(arr1[i] == arr2[i]){    // or while(arr[i].equals(arr2[i]))
    code to put if where equal
    i++;
}
```